# What's the best way to have reusable dialog boxes?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

What's the best way to create reusable dialog boxes in Android?

Reading through the [Dialog dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), I know I can use `AlertDialog.Builder(this);` in one of my `Activity`s, but what if I want to use this in multiple Activities? If this was some other class I would extend it, so `MyDialog extends AlertDialog`, but then I cannot use the `Builder`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crate one class file like as `AllMethod.java` and add this code in that class file.

```
public static void showAlert(Activity act, String msg, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        alert.setMessage(msg);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", listener);
        alert.show();
    }
```

and you can use from any class like below code.

```
AllMethod.showAlert(mActivity, "", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         // Do your code for click
         }
});
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but I believe it answered my question. However, if I wanted to add an action to the dialog (say refresh a list in the activity) do I simply add a return value to the function and handle it in the activity?  (after posting this I realized how simple it would be to do this but I'll leave this comment here anyway)

Comment: if you want refresh list on "OK" button of dialog then add your refresh code(adapter.notifyDataChange()) in onClick of positive button and add Negative button for nothing to do.

Comment: @CapDroid if you manually add code to your onClick  handler then this dialog box is no longer *reusable* or would in fact be tightly coupled to the business logic of the caller.