# how to display one popup window in all activitys?

Tags: android

Developing sample download application,My application contains 3 activities.When the first activity starts, the download begins automatically. when the download is completed I have set a code to raise a popup.Will the same popup raises in the all other activities also.Please let  me know if I need to put any code to get the popup in the other activities too.pls tell me how to do this.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241169/how-to-use-a-custom-dialog-in-all-of-my-application-in-android/7241294#7241294

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026571/whats-the-best-was-to-have-reusable-dialog-boxes/6026620#6026620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is sample code code of using `AlertDialog` in all activity.

crate one class file like as allmethod.java

and add this code in that class

```
public static void showAlert(Activity act,String msg)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
            alert.setMessage(msg).setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {   
                }
            }).show();
        }
```

and you can use from any class like as

```
allmethod.showAlert(Activity,"Message");
```

if you want `PopUp` instead of `AlertDialog` then you can write your code in `showAlert` Method and you can also add parameters whatever you need.

Comment: Hi CapDrop thks for reply , allmethod.showAlert(Activity,"Message") in this method Activity means pass activity context right

Comment: using showAlert(getApplication(),"Message") or showAlert(getApplicationContext,"Message")

Comment: for Context .. youractivityname.this is better

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same pop up to be shown in all the 3 activities then you should make one `Base Activity` and put your pop up code here and extend it in all your 3 activities and now you can call it directly from your code...

Comment: hi vineet shukla,thks for replay pls tell me how to create base activity

Comment: create a activity with name base activity with no view and there define your popup method and in your other activity inspite of extending Activity, write extends BaseActivity and call your popup method from your activity......